# Changing the "Add Url" that is sent to Aweber

Tags: forms, email, submit, aweber

I am looking to find out how to change the "ADD URL" that is sent to aweber. 
We are using a API third party provider and it submits there page url for the sign up page.

So I'd like to know how we can change the URL that is seen in aweber as "ADD URL".

Is there a javascript or something to do this ?

Would that to change it from the actual page to our page ... http://www.domain.com

Answer (score 0):

The "Add URL" field is reserved for AWeber Web Forms and isn't writeable by the API. Your third-party integrator is most likely using the API to simply display an HTML web form, rather than actually submitting the subscribers to your list via the API.

To verify that, you can view the subscriber record in your AWeber account and the Add Method will be listed as "API" or "Web Form".

While I'm not entirely certain of the use case for changing the Add URL when it's presumably already accurate, there are a couple of workarounds for the lack of write access to the field.

In cases like this, you can always use the Ad Tracking field, or a Custom Field instead. You can still do segmenting on any of those fields, and they are fully writeable via the API.

If you need any assistance with using the API, or would like more specific help than can be offered in a public forum, be sure to get in touch with AWeber Customer Solutions - help@aweber.com